# Reverse Tensing of the /æ/ Phoneme in American English?

Tags: american-english, dialects, phonology, linguistics, accent

I am a native speaker of a General American sociolect that realizes the /æ/ phoneme as [ɛə] before nasal consonants (e.g. 'fan,' 'stand,' 'ram'), and I've recently noticed that I've begun un-raising (not the correct terminology I'm sure) the phoneme back into the [æ] sound, which seems contrary to general trends in vowel shifts around the country. I'm a university student in a fairly large university, and thus I've been exposed to English speakers from pretty much every area of the country, however, I have not been able to pinpoint any particular locality that pronounces the phoneme this way. Am I skipping over an obvious dialect, or am I picking something up from international media without realizing it?

Comment: You may simply be regressing to a mean of the folks you interact with, and/or the local lect. It's one way of bonding in a speech group. Good observations, though.